# Поиск по таблице базы данных

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, mariadb

Делаю поиск по таблице, структура таблицы такова:
[image: структура таблицы]

Контент в ней следующий:
[image: контент]

в этой таблице лежат таски, поиск я делаю по столбцу performers где лежат id user-сов которые исполняют эти таски. Так как исполнителей может быть неколько - надо чтобы user-у с id 2, были доступны как и его таски так и те где исполнитель стоит не только он.

Для решения этой задачи я пробовал следующее:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `performers` LIKE '%2%'
```

Возвращает это:
[image: возврат1]
и вот это:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE CONTAINS (`recipient`, 2);
```

Получаю это:
[image: возврат 2]

Подскажите как правильно написать запрос? Гуглеж по документации CONTAINS не помог так как запрос с примера вызвал эту ошибку, а гуглеж самой ошибки привел на сайт мелкомягких где ответа нет

Тип сервера:
[image: server]

Comment: очевидно - для связи между юзерами и тасками использовать промежуточную таблицу task_user со связью многие ко многим, где всего три поля - id, task_id, user_id.

Comment: А как это решит мою проблему? по факту все равно придем к запросу где надо будет наличие юзер ид в поле с несколькими юзерами, или нет?

Comment: нет, будет что то вроде `select * from tasks where task_id in(select task_id from task_user where user_id=2)`. Или то же самое через join. SQL в принципе предназначен для работы именно с такими, нормализованными данными (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) И кстати в этой таблице task_user поле id вообще не нужно. первичным ключем сделать составной прямо из полей (user_id, task_id)

Comment: У вас в таблице будет не одна строчка с id тасков, а столько строк, сколько тасков для юзера. Один такск - одна строчка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не хватает еще одной таблицы для свзи многие-ко-многим. Создайте ее с полями, которые будут внешними ключами: `user_task (user_id, task_id)`. Запрос будет:

```
select * 
from tasks t join user_task u on t.id = u.task_id 
where u.user_id=2
```