# Проблема с полнотекстовым поиском в phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица с данными
[image: таблица]
пишу запрос на поиск строк у которых поле performers содержит 2
[image: результат запроса]
Результат получаю 0, подскажите что я делаю не так и как решить эту проблему? Также альтернативные методы поиска я делал в этом вопросе:
[Поиск по таблице базы данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1143895/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Предложенный там вариант создать еще одну таблицу - мне честно остался непонятен.

Comment: Полнотекст имеет кучу ограничений. Например, innodb_ft_min_token_size. Ищите прямым вхождением. Но ещё лучше - нормализуйте структуру хранения данных.

Comment: Я бы конечно предложил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532322/194569 но у вас там пробелы, а не запятые. А по поводу отдельной таблицы для правильного решения. `create table task_user(task_id int not null, user_id int not null, primary key(user_id, task_id))` и для задачи 22 вставляете в нее 4 записи: (22,1), (22,10), (22,2), (22,20). Как при этом выглядит запрос поиска я вам в прошлый раз написал

Comment: а можно ли как то сделать чтобы при добавлении задачи в эту таблицу автоматом падала соотвествующая запись, чтобы не городить мультизапросы?